Dynamic Columns Headings change based on Slicer selection
i created the a table data where few columns are static and 3 columns data is changing as per the selection in slicer, but is there any way where i can change the headings as well along with the data,enter image description here
I am getting the data by below code, but not able to change headings dynamically, is there any option where i can change headings along with data:
Data 1 = SWITCH([Selected Scenario],"API COGS",SUM(Table1[API RMC]),"Formulation COGS",SUM(Table1[Formulation RMC]))

here is a workaround.
Create two pages, one for API, the other for Formulation
Create two boxes and apply action for them. In the Formulation page, apply the page navigation to API page on the API box.
In the API page, apply the page navigation to Formulation page on the formulation box

then you can click box to switch between two pages


is there any possible solution in the existing page it self by changing the headers, since values are coming properly

so far I don't have any other solution that can work in the same page. Let's see if anyone  else can provide you the better solution.
